# I found error in kotlin java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.scrollupstudio.projemanag.models.Task

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I found an error in kotlin when I update data on Cloud Firestore:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.scrollupstudio.projemanag.models.Task
  
    at com.scrollupstudio.projemanag.firebase.FirestoreClass.addUpdateTaskList(FirestoreClass.kt:155)
    at com.scrollupstudio.projemanag.activities.TaskListActivity.createTaskList(TaskListActivity.kt:63)
    at com.scrollupstudio.projemanag.adapters.TaskListItemAdapter$onBindViewHolder$3.onClick(TaskListItemAdapter.kt:63)
```

This is the code error on update(taskListHashMap)

```
fun addUpdateTaskList(activity: TaskListActivity, board: Board){
    val taskListHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    taskListHashMap[Constants.TASK_LIST] = board.taskList

    Log.d("FirestoreClass", "id : ${board.documentId} dengan ini : ${taskListHashMap.toString()}")
    mFirestore.collection(Constants.BOARDS)
        .document(board.documentId)
        .update(taskListHashMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName, "TaskList update successfully")
            activity.addUpdateTaskListSuccess()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            exception ->
            activity.hidePorgressDialog()
            Log.e(activity.javaClass.simpleName, "Error", exception)
        }
}
```

This is my Board model:

```
@Parcelize
data class Board(
    val name: String = "",
    val image: String = "",
    val crearedBy: String = "",
    val assignedTo: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(),
    var documentId: String = "",
    var taskList: ArrayList<Task> = ArrayList()
): Parcelable
```

This is my Task model:

```
@Parcelize
data class Task(
    var title: String = "",
    val createdBy: String = ""
): Parcelable
```

/sc

Comment: At which exact line of code does that error occur?

Comment: error on  update(taskListHashMap) in fun addUpdateTaskList

Comment: Have you tried to update a property directly without a HashMap?

Comment: yes, it is can't